Is there a function in R that can handle a pathfinding algorithm with an objective value and constraints?
I have done all my coding in RStudio, but I am more than willing to try any other coding language that may be better suited for this issue.
I have a dataset which contains the latitude and longitude of a variety of 79 locations, where each location has a value_generated and a processing_time. For my thesis, I need to come up with an algorithm which has the capability of producing an optimal path, such that the locations selected on the path produce the greatest summed value of 'value_generated' while simultaneously ensuring that the '(total_travel_time + total_processing_time) <= max_time. '
The travel times are calculated by using the calculated distance between each point, and applying a 10mph travel speed. The constraint of '(total_travel_time + total_processing_time) <= max_time makes' it impossible for all the locations to be reached, therefore the optimal path will only contain a subset of the total locations that can be selected.
These are real locations, so using actual maps and road networks are preferable, but not necessary. I want the model to produce a path that makes the highest summed value of (value_generated), in a way that the processing and travel time does not exceed the time in a year.
I have tried a somewhat brute force method with a greedy algorithm, where the model simply selects what locations to go to by a 'best-score', where the best-score is calculated as (where social_cost is equivalent to value_generated above):
'   score <- individual_social_cost - (individual_processing_time + individual_travel_time)'
Which results in the model choosing what the best score is based on where the model is currently. This resulted in a path being generated, but it had irrational choices. For example, the path may be 1, 7, 10, 15, 30 ; which results in a high value generated. However, the model will provide this as the optimal path even if 7 and 15 are right next to each other. In which case the optimal route, which would provide the same amount of value generated, would instead be 1, 7, 15, 10, 30 ; which would therefore minimize the travel distance.

find_optimal_path <- function(deschutes_nf, max_time) {
  num_locations <- nrow(deschutes_nf)
  distances <- matrix(0, nrow = num_locations, ncol = num_locations)
  
  # Calculate distances between locations
  for (i in 1:num_locations) {
    for (j in 1:num_locations) {
      distances[i, j] <- calculate_distance_miles(deschutes_nf[i,], deschutes_nf[j,])
    }
  }
  
  current_location <- 1  # Start from location 1
  visited_locations <- c(current_location)
  remaining_locations <- setdiff(1:num_locations, current_location)
  
  total_social_cost <- 0
  total_processing_time <- 0
  total_distance <- 0
  total_travel_time <- 0
  total_time <- 0 
  
  while (length(remaining_locations) > 0) {
    best_location <- NULL
    best_score <- -Inf
    
    # Step 1: Evaluate feasibility of adding next location to the path
    for (next_location in remaining_locations) {
      path <- c(visited_locations, next_location)
      
      # Calculate total social cost, processing time, distance, and travel time
      total_social_cost_candidate <- sum(deschutes_nf[path, "social_cost"])
      total_processing_time_candidate <- sum(deschutes_nf[path, "processing_time"])
      total_distance_candidate <- sum(distances[path[1:(length(path)-1)], path[2:length(path)]])
      total_travel_time_candidate <- sum(calculate_travel_time(distances[path[1:(length(path)-1)], path[2:length(path)]]))
      
      # Calculate total time including processing and travel time
      total_time_candidate <- total_processing_time_candidate + total_travel_time_candidate
      
      # Check if constraints are satisfied
      if (total_time_candidate <= max_time) {
        # Step 2: Evaluate individual contribution of next location to the path
        individual_social_cost <- deschutes_nf[next_location, "social_cost"]
        individual_processing_time <- deschutes_nf[next_location, "processing_time"]
        individual_distance <- distances[visited_locations[length(visited_locations)], next_location]
        individual_travel_time <- calculate_travel_time(individual_distance)
        
        # Calculate score based on individual contribution and distance penalty
score <- individual_social_cost - (individual_processing_time + individual_travel_time) - (10 * individual_distance)

        
        # Update the best location if the current candidate has a higher score
        if (score > best_score) {
          best_location <- next_location
          best_score <- score
          best_processing_time <- individual_processing_time
          best_distance <- individual_distance
          best_travel_time <- individual_travel_time
          best_social_cost <- individual_social_cost
        }
      }
    }
    
    # If a feasible location is found, move to that location
    if (!is.null(best_location)) {
      current_location <- best_location
      visited_locations <- c(visited_locations, current_location)
      remaining_locations <- remaining_locations[remaining_locations != current_location]
      total_social_cost <- total_social_cost + best_social_cost  
      total_processing_time <- total_processing_time + best_processing_time
      total_distance <- total_distance + best_distance
      total_travel_time <- total_travel_time + best_travel_time
      total_time <- total_processing_time + total_travel_time
    } else {
      # If no feasible location is found, break the loop
      break 
    }
  }
  
  return(list(path = visited_locations, total_social_cost = total_social_cost, 
              total_processing_time = total_processing_time, total_distance = total_distance, 
              total_travel_time = total_travel_time, total_time = total_time))
}
    ```



isn't this the salesman problem?

The traveling salesman problem is trying to find the shortest path between a set of locations. Here, we are implementing something similar, however we do not need to reach all the locations, and are instead choosing the path based on what makes the value of 'social_cost' the highest. In the Traveling Salesman Problem, there is also not an issue of being constrained by an amount of time. Here we have to choose the most locations possible, which results in the greatest sum of 'social_cost' while also not letting the selected locations' (processing_time + travel_time) <= max_time.

Okay, I see the differences, though it still sounds like an optimization problem but minimizing different variables and with the added constraint of "max_time". This is NP-hard, so I suggest a brute-force nested-for-loop is not going to scale well. I haven't used it, but have you see the TSP package?

I have taken a look into it, but it doesn't seem to have an option for selecting a path that optimizes a value associated with each location. A simpler version of the problem is: location 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 have social cost values of 5, 8, 10, 7, 15 and processing times of 50, 80, 100, 70, 150. Choose as many locations as possible which results in highest sum of social cost, without exceeding 200 units of time. This would give you likely a solution of 1, 5 as a path or 1, 2, 4 as a path. The issue is that the TSP is trying to minimize the distance if I wanted to get to all 5 locations.

79 is not a huge number, so brute force may be feasible. You should provide a complete runnable program.
